# Why am I getting an incompatible pointer type warning here ?

Tags: c, list, struct, stack, declaration

I've implemented a very basic stack here as an exercise, using a linked list.

My program has the following three files.

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {int content; struct node *next;};

void push(struct Node **node, int i);
int pop(struct Node **node);

#endif
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

void push(struct Node **node, int i)
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (!(*node)){
        (*new_node).content = i;
        (*new_node).next = NULL;
        *node = new_node;

        return;
    }

    (*new_node).content = i;
    (*new_node).next = (struct Node *)*node;
    *node = new_node;

    return;
}

int pop(struct Node **node)
{
    if (*node == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct Node *temp = (**node).next;
    int i = (**node).content;

    free(*node);
    *node = temp;

    return i;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

struct Node *top = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    push(&top, 2);
    printf("%d\n\n", pop(&top));
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this however, I get the following warnings

```
stack.c: In function ‘push’:
stack.c:18:19: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  (*new_node).next = (struct Node *)*node;
                   ^
stack.c: In function ‘pop’:
stack.c:31:22: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
    struct Node *temp = (**node).next;
                        ^
```

Though the program runs despite these warnings and gives the correct output, but I'd still like to understand why this is happening.

Why am I getting these warnings ? And how do I fix them ?

Comment: `Node` vs `node`. By the way, don't use casts to get around errors because all that does is hide the errors, not fix them.

Comment: looks like a typo `struct node *next;` should be `struct Node *next;`

Comment: You should use `new_node->content` syntax instead of `(*new_node).content`

Comment: You should also not cast things to types they already have, like in `(struct Node *)*node`.

Answer (score 2):

Due to a typo in this declaration

```
struct Node {int content; struct node *next;};
       ^^^^                      ^^^^
```

there are declared two types `struct Node` and `struct node` that are incompatible types.

As for the functions then they can be defined simpler. For example the function `push` can be declared the following way.

```
int push( struct Node **node, int i )
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        (*new_node).content = i;
        (*new_node).next = *node;
        *node = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to exit the program if the stack is empty. You should also rewrite the function `pop`.

For example the function can be declared like

```
int pop( struct Node **node, int *i );
```

In case the stack is empty the function returns `0`. Otherwise it returns `1` and in the expression `*i` the value of the node.